# Undeclared Identifier in separate compilation

Tags: c++, visual-c++

It's been a while since I last coded using separate compilation so I'm a bit embarrassed that I can't figure out what is causing such a rudimentary error.

Here is the code in question from my "SpaceInvader.h" file:

```
#pragma once

#include "ClassDemoApp.h"
#include "SpriteSheet.h"
#include "Bullet.h"
#include <vector>

class Character{

public:
    Character(float newU, float newV, float newWidth, float newHeight, float newX, float newY, std::vector <Bullet> newVolley);

private:
    float thisU;
    float thisV;
    float thisWidth;
    float thisHeight;

    float xPos;
    float yPos;

    bool isDead;

    std::vector <Bullet> volley;
};
```

I'm getting a `C2065: 'Bullet' : undeclared identifier` in my constructor and in the private variable declaration.

For the record, this is my "Bullet.h" file:

```
#pragma once

#include "SpriteSheet.h"

class Bullet{

public:
    Bullet(float u, float v, float w, float h, const char *name);
    void normalFire();

private:
    float bulletU;
    float bulletV;
    float bulletW;
    float bulletH;

    const char *imageName;
};
```

I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong here because my Bullet class *is* being declared but I have no idea why the compiler doesn't recognize it.

Comment: The bug might be in some other header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have a loop in your header dependencies. Something like Bullet.h includes SpriteSheet.h which includes SpaceInvader.h, which tries to include Bullet.h again, which will be ignored (because it is already included).

This means that when the compiler is processing SpaceInvader.h, it does not know what `Bullet` is, because it hasn't fully processed Bullet.h

More detail on what is happening: When the compiler hits a #include line it basically reads that whole file in and replaces the #include with the contents of the file. It then keeps processing the code it just included, it will do the same thing with any more includes it finds. If you have two files that include each other, you will end up with a loop and a compiler error.

One thing that changes that behavior is the `#pragma once` directive, which means that each header will only be included once per compile.

However, all `#pragma once` does is effectively replace any `#include` statements for files that have already been done with blank text.

You can think of it as if you are in the text editor and just cut-and-pasting the whole include file in where the `#include` line is. Actually, I'd recommend doing it in this case to see what is going wrong - cut and paste your original cpp into a blank document, then one at a time replace the `#include` lines with their text content. If you come to a #include for a file you have already done, just remove it.

So in your case what happens is that the definition of the `Bullet` class is still further down in the file that the compiler is building up.

Simplest solution in this case is to not include Bullet.h from SpaceInvader.h, but just forward declare the class. Remove the include and use this line instead:

```
class Bullet;
```

Edit:
Note - you will have to include Bullet.h in SpaceInvader.cpp, so that the compiler knows what it is before you start using it.

Comment: The loop was a bit longer than that but that is what happened nonetheless (there was a SpaceInvader<->ClassDemoApp loop and a Bullet->SpriteSheet->SpaceInvader one).

So is what you are saying is that Bullet.h takes longer to compile than SpaceInvader.h because the loop is longer?

Also, forward declaration. Noted. It sounds very familiar but after reading a few pages about it after reading your post, it's definitely something I need to familiarize myself with.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: It isn't anything to do with how long something takes to compile - I'll edit my post a bit to be more clear.